# How to perform match on sum of two fields

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a query in MySQL that contains the following condition:

```
WHERE START_TIME < ? AND START_TIME+DURATION >= ?
```

How should I migrate this to MongoDB using Java driver and aggregation framework?
The first condition will become:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("start_time", "{ $lt : "+timestamp+"}") );
```

But I'm not sure about the second.
Thanks.

**EDIT**
I've tried to work with Asya Kamsky answer, this is what I got but it's not working:

```
BasicDBList dbList = new BasicDBList();
dbList.add("$start_time");
dbList.add("$duration");

DBObject matchLT = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("start_time", new BasicDBObject("$lt",timestamp)));
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("end_time", new BasicDBObject("$add", dbList)));
DBObject matchGTE = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("end_time", new BasicDBObject("$gte",timestamp)));
//GROUP CODE GOES HERE
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(matchLT, project, matchGTE, group);
```

Comment: I wonder why people are down voting without a comment. Or an answer.

Comment: Dunno maybe the java is clearly wrong or something, I don't program Java atm however, you want to do your match and then a projection using $add and then another match on that computed field

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in Aggregation Framework, I'm sure you can translate this to Java:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$match: {start_time:{$lt:ISODate("xxxx-xx-xx")}}},
           {$project:{end_time:{$add:["$start_time","$duration"]}}},
           {$match:{end_time:{$gt:ISODate("yyyy-yy-yy")}}}
] );
```